# Compojure + clojure.contrib.sql: SELECT query is being cached. Why?

Tags: sql, mysql, clojure, compojure, clojure-contrib

I'm writing a Compojure TODO app and with MySQL as the primary data store. I'm using clojure.contrib.sql to interface with MySQL as follows:

```
(def db {:classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         :subprotocol "mysql"
         :subname "//localhost:3306/todo"
         :user "<user>"
         :password ""})
```

The queries I'm using seem to work, however the results appear to be cached. For example, after running

```
(with-connection db
  (insert-values :todos
    [:name] [name]))
```

the value is successfully inserted into the database. However,

```
(defn sql-query [query]
  (with-connection db
    (with-query-results rows [query]
      (into [] rows))))
```

returns the same value, regardless of how many items are inserted. Of course, if I restart the web app, the results are updated, but this doesn't seem very production-friendly :).

Any idea why this would be happening? Thanks in advance.

As requested, here is the top-level form for the SELECT query:

```
(def home-view
  (render
    (base {:title "Clojure Todo"
           :content (apply str
             (map #(% :name)
               (sql-query "select * from todos")))})))
```

Comment: This sounds similar to the way SQL Server caches execution plans for queries that are run in an effort to boost performance for the database, preventing optimisation of the queries each time they are executed.

Comment: Have a look at this article to learn about query caching in MySQL: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3110171/MySQLs-Query-Cache.htm That might well be the cause. BTW, the thing being cached is the actual result set; caching just the execution plan would have no impact on the correctness of the results returned.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with MySQL, I think it's a Clojure issue.

Comment: Are you sure the clojure sql code commits the transactions? If it keeps a transaction open but commits them during shutdown to cleanup it would explain what your seeing. It's a long shot but you could try doing them in an explicit transaction with a commit. Or you could look to see if mysql has any open transactions while the application is running.

Comment: I do know that the insert is committed. As for the select, I have no idea. How would I go about checking to see if there is a transaction in progress in MySQL?

Comment: Could you try running the insert statement *first*, before any select queries, and only then check what a select will return (i.e. whether the newly inserted rows will be included in the result)? Also, any particular reason why you think it's more likely to be an issue with Clojure (or c.c.sql) than with MySQL? (To be clear, I'm just asking to try and get a clearer picture of the situation.)

Comment: Oh, one more thing: how do you run that select query? From the REPL? From within your webapp? In the latter case, could you provide some context (say, what does the top-level form in which your `with-connection` block related to the select query occurs look like)?

Comment: I'm running the select query from within the webapp...the top-level form is basically `(defroutes todo (GET "/" [] home-view))`, where `home-view` is what is defined above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the most recently added comment on the answer together with the most recent update to the question text I gather that the problem is nothing to do with `clojure.contrib.sql`, it's with the `defroutes` form.

`(defroutes todo (GET "/" [] home-view))` means that requests matching this route will receive `home-view` as a reply. Now `home-view` is evaluated only once, when the `(def home-view ...)` form is evaluated -- and in particular, the associated SQL query is executed only once.

To fix this, rewrite `home-view` as a function and have the route call it, perhaps like so:

```
(defn home-view []
  ...the render form from your old (def home-view ...) form goes here...
  )

(defroutes todo (GET "/" [] (home-view)))
```

Then `home-view`-the-function will be called each time the route gets triggered (and execute its SQL query once per each such call).

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks for your help!